# Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead at line 33?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

`array=[  45000.   50000.   60000.   80000.  110000.  150000.  200000.  300000.
  500000. 1000000.]`.

Below error message is coming while using SVM. The array is a numpy array.

> Reshape your data either using `array.reshape(-1, 1)` if your data has
>   a single feature or `array.reshape(1, -1)` if it contains a single
>   sample.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is already in your question. You are providing a 1D array to a function that expects a 2D array. You can add an empty dimension to your 1D array to convert it to 2D using `array.reshape(-1, 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it.

1. You can put the array into `[]`
2. you can do `array = array.reshape(-1, 1)`.

The error message is already showing you the answer as correctly pointed out by @Abhineet